# FFMPEG / libav: How is UYVY422 written inside AVFrame structure?

Tags: ffmpeg, libavcodec, libav

I'm trying to copy frame data from `AVFrame` structure to a buffer. I know how to do that with `YUV420P` format since Y data is stored inside `AVFrame frame->data[0]`, U data is stored inside `AVFrame frame->data[1]` and V data is stored inside `AVFrame frame->data[2]`, so it was easy to `memcpy()` Y,U and V data separately + it's planar format so i was able to do that with ease:

```
for (y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        memcpy(buffer + y*frame->linesize[0], frame->data[0] + y*frame->linesize[0], width);
    }

    buffer += ySize;

    for (y = 0; y < height / 2; y++)
    {
        memcpy(buffer + y*frame->linesize[1], frame->data[1] + y*frame->linesize[1], width / 2);
    }

    buffer += uSize;

    for (y = 0; y < height / 2; y++)
    {
        memcpy(buffer + y*frame->linesize[2], frame->data[2] + y*frame->linesize[2], width / 2);
    }
```

But when it comes to `UYVY422` i have no idea how the data is stored inside the structure. I have general knowledge about `UYVY422` format and that it's written like it name suggests UYVYUYVYUYVY... and so on. But my question is how do i know how much data is stored in `AVFrame frame->data[0]`, `AVFrame frame->data[1]` and `AVFrame frame->data[2]` field so i can `memcpy()` exact amount to the buffer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For UYVY, the data is stored exclusively in frame->data[0], and per line you should copy width * 2 bytes:

```
for (y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    memcpy(output_buffer + y*frame->linesize[0],
           frame->data[0] + y*frame->linesize[0], width * 2);
}
```

There's a way to programmatically derive this, in case you're interested. Each `AVPixelFormat` has a [`AVPixFmtDescriptor`](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVPixFmtDescriptor.html) that describes its packing in `AVFrame->data[]`. To get yours, use [`av_pix_fmt_desc_get`](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/pixdesc_8h.html#afe0c3e8aef5173de28bbdaea4298f5f0)`(`[`AV_PIX_FMT_UYVY`](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/pixfmt_8h.html#a9a8e335cf3be472042bc9f0cf80cd4c5a4b8a29937744c722f35fccafb91ebdf0)`)`. The returned item is [this](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/pixdesc_8c_source.html#l00345) one (see struct reference for [`AVComponentDescriptor`](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVComponentDescriptor.html) here). You'll see that `desc->nb_components` is 3, `desc->log2_chroma_w` is 1, which means U/V are subsampled by 1 horizontally, and `desc->comp[0-2].plane` is 0, which means all data is in `AVFrame->data[0]`. The `offset`/`step`/`depth` in `desc->comp[0-2]` tell you the rest in case you want a fully dynamic way of reading any pix_fmt. I don't think you personally need it, but at the very least it allows anyone to derive the packing of any pix_fmt in `AVFrame->data[]`.

[edit] See following example code (possibly buggy):

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libavutil/pixdesc.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [fmt]\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    const char *fmtname = argv[1];
    enum AVPixelFormat fmt = av_get_pix_fmt(fmtname);
    if (fmt == AV_PIX_FMT_NONE) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unknown pixfmt %s\n", fmtname);
        return 1;
    }
    const AVPixFmtDescriptor *desc = av_pix_fmt_desc_get(fmt);
    assert(desc != NULL);
    printf("N planes: %d, %d bits/element\n", desc->nb_components, desc->comp[0].depth);

    int n;
    int epl[4] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    int width = 0x100;
    for (n = 0; n < desc->nb_components; n++) {
        int is_y = n == 0;
        int is_a = !(desc->nb_components & 1) && n == desc->nb_components - 1;
        int h_ss = (is_y || is_a) ? 0 : desc->log2_chroma_w;

        epl[desc->comp[n].plane] += width >> h_ss;
    }

    for (n = 0; n < 4; n++) {
        int is_y = n == 0;
        int is_a = !(desc->nb_components & 1) && n == desc->nb_components - 1;
        int v_ss = (is_y || is_a) ? 0 : desc->log2_chroma_h;

        if (epl[n] == 0) continue;
        printf("Plane %d has %lf elements/y_pixel (horizontally) and %lf lines/y_pixel (vertically)\n",
               n, epl[n] / (double) width, (width >> v_ss) / (double) width);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Which gives the following output:

```
$ for fmt in yuyv422 uyvy422 yuv420p yuva420p10; do /tmp/test $fmt; done
N planes: 3, 8 bits/element
Plane 0 has 2.000000 elements/y_pixel (horizontally) and 1.000000 lines/y_pixel (vertically)
N planes: 3, 8 bits/element
Plane 0 has 2.000000 elements/y_pixel (horizontally) and 1.000000 lines/y_pixel (vertically)
N planes: 3, 8 bits/element
Plane 0 has 1.000000 elements/y_pixel (horizontally) and 1.000000 lines/y_pixel (vertically)
Plane 1 has 0.500000 elements/y_pixel (horizontally) and 0.500000 lines/y_pixel (vertically)
Plane 2 has 0.500000 elements/y_pixel (horizontally) and 0.500000 lines/y_pixel (vertically)
N planes: 4, 10 bits/element
Plane 0 has 1.000000 elements/y_pixel (horizontally) and 1.000000 lines/y_pixel (vertically)
Plane 1 has 0.500000 elements/y_pixel (horizontally) and 0.500000 lines/y_pixel (vertically)
Plane 2 has 0.500000 elements/y_pixel (horizontally) and 0.500000 lines/y_pixel (vertically)
Plane 3 has 1.000000 elements/y_pixel (horizontally) and 1.000000 lines/y_pixel (vertically)
```

Comment: Oh god, thank you so much. I have no idea that i could find that out from their source. I mean, obviously, description has to be somewhere but i had no idea where to look. This is so good i can't even describe how thrilled i am. Now i can try compression between any pixel format and find out which one works the best/fastest. One thing that i don't quite understand is the `AVComponentDescriptor->step`, everything else is self explanatory. For example,YUV420P's step is set to 1, does that mean that there is 1 chroma element between 2 horizontally consecutive pixels?

Comment: Also, how can i deduce how many bytes do i need to copy from `AVFrame->data[0]` per line?

Comment: The step means "how many elements do I need to increment my pointer to get to the next element of this type". Example: UYVY layout is exactly that: U1Y1V1Y2U2Y3V2Y4[etc]. So, if my uint8_t *ptr is set to U1, how many elements (uint8_t) do I need to increment it to get to U2? 4! And for Y1 to Y2? 2! For most planar pixel formats, this value is always 1. The value is only > 1 for non-planar pixel formats (or mixed formats like the chroma plane in NV12).

Comment: How many bytes to copy "in general"... So, the complex answer to this is that you would need an array of int data_buffers[MAX_PLANES] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 } (assume MAX_PLANES=4). Then, for each component in desc->nb_components, check desc->comp[idx].plane and increment that plane by width or width >> desc->log2_chroma_w, depending on whether this plane type is luma/alpha or chroma. Then, for each plane index in data_buffers[idx], copy that many bytes per line from AVFrame->data[idx]. But for quick hacks/tries, it may be simpler to derive it on a case-by-case basis...

Comment: Oh cool, so step depends on type of data, which in this case is uin8_t* and how the format is packed. And how could i derive it on a case-by-case basis? For YUV420P is pretty obvious since there are 3 planes but for UYVY422 there is only 1 plane describing data, but i can't find anywhere that amount of bytes needed to copy for 1 line is 2 * width of the frame.